# How to set Background Color to button on OnCreate method In android

Tags: android, web-services

I have created web-service i am receiving data from that i have fetch the table status from the database in that status there is a two status one is empty or second is processing but problem is that i need to compare that to android button and check the condition if the status is processing then i want to set-background color red to button else empty button is green.I have problem to setting the background color of button on page load. I have added images below

[This is the windows screen i have fetch data of this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCRAp.png)

[This is my android button i need to set color to this button same like above screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTsh2.png)

Comment: show us what have you tried and where you are facing problem.

Comment: are you calling asyncTask for web services request? then you can take each button and give them the two colors one in preExecute() {yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.RED)); }and 

another one is postExecute(){yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREEN)); };

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a `Color` to a `Button` in `onCreate()` you can do it like this.

```
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor)); 
//yourcolor should have been defined in your resources
```